# expressJS: How to push socketIO on get call?

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io

This is how I set up a simple expressJS server with a socket.IO connection.

My application is reading some sensor data every 10 seconds, which gets pushed to every client. This is no problem for me.

But also one client can call `/set-status` with some parameter to change some status data. In that case the new status data should be send to every client. That's why a simple request/response attempt is not working.

What do I have to do to push the socketIO connection after `/set-status` has been called?

```
const express = require('express')
const http = require('http')
const socketIo = require('socket.io')

const app = express()
const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = socketIo(server)

io.on('connection', socket => {
  getStatus(socket)
  getData(socket)
  setInterval(
    () => getData(socket),
    10000
  )
})

app.get('/set-status', (req, res) => {
  // Change some data and push new data to every client
  // How to get access to socket?
  res.send(200, 'new-data')
})

const getStatus = async socket => {
  const res = { initial: 'data' }
  socket.emit('exampleStatus', res)
}

const getData = async socket => {
  // read some sensor data, which is refreshed every 10 sec.
  // this is working as expected
  const res = { some: 'sensor data' }
  socket.emit('sensorData', res)
}

server.listen(port, () => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`)
  }
})
```

Comment: Call `getData()` within your `get` handler for the `/set-status` route.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I need to call `getStatus` within the `get` handler. But I'm missing the `socket` parameter. That's why I cannot call `getStatus()`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. You'll need a reference to the socket then right?   You have two options. 1) create a named channel (more complex but probably more correct) OR 2) create a global that holds the reference and use the global throughout.

Comment: An alternative, of course, is to use the socket to send the new status. That would be the ideal way really. Subscribe->send update event->broadcast update. Simple.

Comment: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/examples/chat/index.js

Comment: @RandyCasburn Don't I just have to call `getStatus(io)`?

Comment: is `io` of type socket or type 'io'? Won't work because you'll need the socket and not the driver.

Comment: After taking a bit of a close look, I'm confused about your sensor data source. As written, it is the same socket. Can you explain how your sensor data is populating the socket without listeners assigned to those sensor events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If client sockets are listening for `exampleStatus` events, you can emit an `exampleStatus` event from inside of your `get` callback. It would look like this: `io.emit('exampleStatus', data)`. On your client sockets, you can write a listener which looks like `socket.on('exampleStatus, data => // do something with data)`.

Comment: Is this a comment or an answer? It might be a good idea to expand upon your answer a little as it is rather terse.